# How to accumulate histogram?

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure

I have data ranging from 0 to 1e5 (in microseconds). I want to make histogram for successive 2.68 microseconds binning for 0.05 microseconds and finally accumulate all the histograms. I have following attempt:

```
a=load('Data.dat')
Range=2.68; % For every successive 2.68micro seconds, I want to plot histogram
n= max(a)/Range; % This tells how many such ranges will be in the data
low=min(a);
high=min(a)+Range;
x=low:0.05:high;
y=hist(a,x);% This is the first histogram for the first 2.68 microsecond
figure
semilogy(x,y,'-ob')

for num=1:1:n-1  % This loop is to make histogram for successive 2.68 microseconds
low=low+Range;
high=high+Range;
x=low:0.05:high;
y=y+hist(a,x-low); % This (I AM NOT SURE) is intended to accumulate the histogram for each  loop. 
end

figure
semilogy(x-low,y,'-or'); % Final accumulated histogram.
```

This is the program I made. But it seems the histogram is not getting accumulated fore each run of the loop. Can anyone help me to accumulate the histogram? Or any other better ways to accumulate histogram for the successive ranges?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do. `hist(a,x-low)` will remain constant for each iteration of the loop, rigth? You are calling the function with the exact same numbers each time

Comment: @AnderBiguri : I am using x-low in order to fit the x axis when I finally accumulate the histogram. As you can see, after each loop the x values shift forward by a range 2.68 microsecond. In order to put on top to top (accumulate) the x values should be adjusted after each loop. What I want to know is 'what is happening in every successive 2.68 microsecond?'.So histogram of successive 2.8 microseconds need to be accumulated.

Comment: @AnderBiguri : I am not sure if there is some other better way to accumulate histogram after each run. Please suggest me if there is some other way. Thank you.

Comment: `x-low` is allways the same value each iteration rigth? I mean `x=low:0.05:high` -> `x-low=low-low:0.05:high-low` -> `x-low=0:0.05:high-low` and `high-low` is `Range`, therefore constant. so the input to `hist` is always `a` and `0:0.05:Range`.

Comment: To correct your code i need to know how `a` is. they are values taken each how many microseconds? Whats the sampling frequenzy? I cant understand why `n=max(a)/Range. are the values of `a` microseconds? If so, what do you want to make histogram of?

Comment: @AnderBiguri : Yes, you are right. x-low is the range and it is the same for all the iteration. n=max(a)/Range determines how many times the for loop should run. Because, my data is very large. I need to accumulate histogram for every successive 2.68microseconds. So max(a)/Range determines how many such ranges are in my data. First outside the loop, I am having histogram for the very first 2.68microsecond. So the loop need to run only for the next n-1 times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65590/discussion-between-ander-biguri-and-aneshps).

Comment: a is the data measured in microseconds. It has a resolution of 0.05 microseconds.

Comment: I put a sample data in chat... Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing it rigth. There are a couple of things you are not doing correctly:

First, the number of pieces of a is not properly computed. To know the amount of pieces youneed to do you need the frequenzy of the data.

```
freq=0.05; %seeing your comments
n=numel(a)*freq/Range;
nindexRange=Range/freq;   %how many data is in each Range
```

This will give you the number of pieces to calculate. However, note that this will not be an integer in general. We need to count for that also.

```
lastpiece=numel(a)-floor(n)*nindexRange; 
% This gives us how many elements are we leaving for the last calculation
```

Therefore lets make n an integer

```
n=floor(n); %round it to the lowest
```

Now you want to get only a piece of the data, adn compute the histogram for it for the same amount of values. Lets say that you want an histogram with 10 bins;

```
nbins=10;
bins=linspace(min(a),max(a),nbins);
```

Now we have defined the values of `a` of wich we want the histogram to count on. Lets loop

```
for ii=1:n
   y=y+hist( a(1 + (ii-1)*nindexRange : nindexRange*ii) , bins);  
end
```

So what are we doing there?
we are taking just a piece of `a` each iteration, and always getting the histogram of the same bins (else accumulating it wont make sense). So how do we acces data? a`(1 + (ii-1)*nindexRange : nindexRange*ii)` try to sort it out, it should be very difficult ;).

but oh! we forget that we left some data out! (because the n is not integer!)

therefore

```
if laspiece~=0
  y=y+hist(a(end-laspiece:end),bins); % take the last "lastpeice" amount of points
end
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Thank you. But there are two problems: 1) The final histogram is not the accumulated one! It seems the histograms are binning together to give back the original data! I think the problem is happening at y=y+hist(a(1 + (ii-1)*nindexRange : nindexRange*ii) , bins). Here, instead of accumulating one by one, it is successively binning one by one! The final histogram is expected to be an accumulation of all the histograms (the histograms obtained for successive 'Range')

Comment: 2) An error in the last 'if loop': Attempted to access a(5057.71); index must be a
positive integer or logical.

Comment: 1) its accumulating the histograms indeed. the result of `hist` is the amount of data in each defined bin. Im not sure what you dont understand. Are you sure what you want is an histogram? 2) indeed, there waas a typo in the function but it should work now